# javascript datepicker with disabled past date

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I use the below JS to create datepicker.  I want to know how do I make the datepicker to grayout and not allow picking of a date that has past? I know this question has been asked before but it is a different script and I am hoping to keep the script with just a minor change to the script. Thanks.

```
var datePickerDivID = "datepicker";
var iFrameDivID = "datepickeriframe";
var dayArrayShort = new Array('S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S');
var dayArrayMed = new Array('Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat');
var dayArrayLong = new Array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday',  'Friday', 'Saturday');
var monthArrayShort = new Array('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec');


var defaultDateSeparator = "/";        
var defaultDateFormat = "mdy"    
var dateSeparator = defaultDateSeparator;
var dateFormat = defaultDateFormat;

function displayDatePicker(dateFieldName, displayBelowThisObject, dtFormat, dtSep)
{  var targetDateField = document.getElementsByName (dateFieldName).item(0);

if (!displayBelowThisObject)
displayBelowThisObject = targetDateField;

if (dtSep)
dateSeparator = dtSep;
  else
dateSeparator = defaultDateSeparator;

if (dtFormat)
dateFormat = dtFormat;
else
dateFormat = defaultDateFormat;

var x = displayBelowThisObject.offsetLeft;
var y = displayBelowThisObject.offsetTop + displayBelowThisObject.offsetHeight ;

var parent = displayBelowThisObject;
while (parent.offsetParent) {
parent = parent.offsetParent;
x += parent.offsetLeft;
y += parent.offsetTop ;
}

drawDatePicker(targetDateField, x, y);}

function drawDatePicker(targetDateField, x, y)
{
var dt = getFieldDate(targetDateField.value );

if (!document.getElementById(datePickerDivID)) {
var newNode = document.createElement("div");
newNode.setAttribute("id", datePickerDivID);
newNode.setAttribute("class", "dpDiv");
newNode.setAttribute("style", "visibility: hidden;");
document.body.appendChild(newNode);
}

var pickerDiv = document.getElementById(datePickerDivID);
pickerDiv.style.position = "absolute";
pickerDiv.style.left = x + "px";
pickerDiv.style.top = y + "px";
pickerDiv.style.visibility = (pickerDiv.style.visibility == "visible" ? "hidden" : "visible");
pickerDiv.style.display = (pickerDiv.style.display == "block" ? "none" : "block");
pickerDiv.style.zIndex = 10000;

refreshDatePicker(targetDateField.name, dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate());}

function refreshDatePicker(dateFieldName, year, month, day)
{
var thisDay = new Date();

if ((month >= 0) && (year > 0)) {
thisDay = new Date(year, month, 1);
 } else {
day = thisDay.getDate();
thisDay.setDate(1);  }

var crlf = "\r\n";
var TABLE = "<table colspan=7 class='dpTable'>" + crlf;
var xTABLE = "</table>" + crlf;
var TR = "<tr class='dpTR'>";
var TR_title = "<tr class='dpTitleTR'>";
var TR_days = "<tr class='dpDayTR'>";
var TR_todaybutton = "<tr class='dpTodayButtonTR'>";
var xTR = "</tr>" + crlf;
var TD = "<td class='dpTD' onMouseOut='this.className=\"dpTD\";' onMouseOver=' this.className=\"dpTDHover\";' ";    
var TD_title = "<td colspan=5 class='dpTitleTD'>";
var TD_buttons = "<td class='dpButtonTD'>";
var TD_todaybutton = "<td colspan=7 class='dpTodayButtonTD'>";
var TD_days = "<td class='dpDayTD'>";
var TD_selected = "<td class='dpDayHighlightTD'   onMouseOut='this.className=\"dpDayHighlightTD\";' onMouseOver='this.className=\"dpTDHover\";' ";    
var xTD = "</td>" + crlf;
var DIV_title = "<div class='dpTitleText'>";
var DIV_selected = "<div class='dpDayHighlight'>";
var xDIV = "</div>";

var html = TABLE;

html += TR_title;
html += TD_buttons + getButtonCode(dateFieldName, thisDay, -1, "&laquo;") + xTD;
html += TD_title + DIV_title + monthArrayLong[ thisDay.getMonth()] + "&nbsp;" + thisDay.getFullYear() + xDIV + xTD;
html += TD_buttons + getButtonCode(dateFieldName, thisDay, 1, "&raquo;") + xTD;
html += xTR;

html += TR_days;
for(i = 0; i < dayArrayMed.length; i++)
html += TD_days + dayArrayMed[i] + xTD;
html += xTR;

html += TR;

for (i = 0; i < thisDay.getDay(); i++)
html += TD + "&nbsp;" + xTD;

 do {
dayNum = thisDay.getDate();
TD_onclick = " onclick=\"updateDateField('" + dateFieldName + "', '" + getDateString(thisDay) + "');\">";

if (dayNum == day)
  html += TD_selected + TD_onclick + DIV_selected + dayNum + xDIV + xTD;
else
  html += TD + TD_onclick + dayNum + xTD;

if (thisDay.getDay() == 6)
  html += xTR + TR;

thisDay.setDate(thisDay.getDate() + 1);
} while (thisDay.getDate() > 1)

if (thisDay.getDay() > 0) {
for (i = 6; i > thisDay.getDay(); i--)
  html += TD + "&nbsp;" + xTD;
}
html += xTR;

var today = new Date();
var todayString = "Today is " + dayArrayMed[today.getDay()] + ", " + monthArrayMed[ today.getMonth()] + ", " + today.getDate();
html += TR_todaybutton + TD_todaybutton;
html += "<button class='dpTodayButtonl' onClick='refreshDatePicker(\"" + dateFieldName + "\");'>this month</button>";
html += "<button class='dpTodayButtonr' onClick='updateDateField(\"" + dateFieldName + "\");'>close</button>";
html += xTD + xTR;

html += xTABLE;

document.getElementById(datePickerDivID).innerHTML = html;
adjustiFrame();
}

function getButtonCode(dateFieldName, dateVal, adjust, label){
var newMonth = (dateVal.getMonth () + adjust) % 12;
var newYear = dateVal.getFullYear() + parseInt((dateVal.getMonth() + adjust) / 12);
if (newMonth < 0) {
newMonth += 12;
newYear += -1;
}

return "<button class='dpButton' onClick='refreshDatePicker(\"" + dateFieldName + "\", " + newYear + ", " + newMonth + ");'>" + label + "</button>";
}

function getDateString(dateVal){
var dayString = "00" + dateVal.getDate();
var monthString = "00" + (dateVal.getMonth()+1);
dayString = dayString.substring(dayString.length - 2);
monthString = monthString.substring(monthString.length - 2);

switch (dateFormat) {
case "dmy" :
  return dayString + dateSeparator + monthString + dateSeparator + dateVal.getFullYear();
case "ymd" :
  return dateVal.getFullYear() + dateSeparator + monthString + dateSeparator + dayString;
case "mdy" :
default :
  return monthString + dateSeparator + dayString + dateSeparator + dateVal.getFullYear();
}}


function getFieldDate(dateString)
{
var dateVal;
var dArray;
var d, m, y;

try {
dArray = splitDateString(dateString);
if (dArray) {
  switch (dateFormat) {
    case "dmy" :
      d = parseInt(dArray[0], 10);
      m = parseInt(dArray[1], 10) - 1;
      y = parseInt(dArray[2], 10);
      break;
    case "ymd" :
      d = parseInt(dArray[2], 10);
      m = parseInt(dArray[1], 10) - 1;
      y = parseInt(dArray[0], 10);
      break;
    case "mdy" :
    default :
      d = parseInt(dArray[1], 10);
      m = parseInt(dArray[0], 10) - 1;
      y = parseInt(dArray[2], 10);
      break;
  }
  dateVal = new Date(y, m, d);
  } else if (dateString) {
  dateVal = new Date(dateString);
  } else {
  dateVal = new Date();
  }} catch(e) {
  dateVal = new Date();}

  return dateVal;}

  function splitDateString(dateString){
  var dArray;
  if (dateString.indexOf("/") >= 0)
  dArray = dateString.split("/");
  else if (dateString.indexOf(".") >= 0)
  dArray = dateString.split(".");
  else if (dateString.indexOf("-") >= 0)
  dArray = dateString.split("-");
  else if (dateString.indexOf("\\") >= 0)
  dArray = dateString.split("\\");
  else
  dArray = false;

  return dArray;  }

  function updateDateField(dateFieldName, dateString){
  var targetDateField = document.getElementsByName (dateFieldName).item(0);
  if (dateString)
  targetDateField.value = dateString;

  var pickerDiv = document.getElementById(datePickerDivID);
  pickerDiv.style.visibility = "hidden";
  pickerDiv.style.display = "none";

  adjustiFrame();
  targetDateField.focus();

  if ((dateString) && (typeof(datePickerClosed) == "function"))
  datePickerClosed(targetDateField);
  }

  function adjustiFrame(pickerDiv, iFrameDiv)
  {
  var is_opera = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("opera") != -1);
  if (is_opera)
  return;

  try {
  if (!document.getElementById(iFrameDivID)) {
  var newNode = document.createElement("iFrame");
  newNode.setAttribute("id", iFrameDivID);
  newNode.setAttribute("src", "javascript:false;");
  newNode.setAttribute("scrolling", "no");
  newNode.setAttribute ("frameborder", "0");
  document.body.appendChild(newNode);}

  if (!pickerDiv)
  pickerDiv = document.getElementById(datePickerDivID);
  if (!iFrameDiv)
  iFrameDiv = document.getElementById(iFrameDivID);

  try {
  iFrameDiv.style.position = "absolute";
  iFrameDiv.style.width = pickerDiv.offsetWidth;
  iFrameDiv.style.height = pickerDiv.offsetHeight ;
  iFrameDiv.style.top = pickerDiv.style.top;
  iFrameDiv.style.left = pickerDiv.style.left;
  iFrameDiv.style.zIndex = pickerDiv.style.zIndex - 1;
  iFrameDiv.style.visibility = pickerDiv.style.visibility ;
  iFrameDiv.style.display = pickerDiv.style.display;
  } catch(e) {      }} catch (ee) {      }}
```

Comment: Have you considered using an existing library for a datepicker? For example, jQuery UI has a good datepicker that is highly configurable. You can gray out dates that have past easily. http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: This is totally not needed, as you have tried and tested date pickers like the jQuery UI one with the exact features you need (disabled past dates, date-randes etc..). You *really* should not be re-inventing the wheel on this one.

Comment: I really hope that this is a personal project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the JQuery UI like Aaron and techfoobar have suggested.  You can use their Theme Roller http://jqueryui.com/themeroller to customize the look if needed.  Very easy to implement.